# What is an alternative solution to the problem of polygon collider2D not following character (animation)movement?

Tags: unity, animation, character, collider, polygoncollider2d

A 2D game and a bird's eye view of the character. This character, who has a knife in his hand, swings the knife by waving his arm, just at this time, I look at "polygon collider2d" from the unity "scene" tab and it does not follow the character's arm or knife. Therefore, the character's knife, arm go into the wall or don't damage the enemy. Because the polygon collider2d is only scaled when the character is in the "idle" state.

My question is right here, do I need to add polygon collider2d separately for each frame of my attack animation and make them active/passive while the animation is playing?

Doesn't doing this degrade performance? I couldn't find an alternative solution.

Solution Edit : The only way to solve this problem is to keep our sprites in separate pieces and prepare the animations we want from unity's own animation window.

Note: In the classical method, we can create animation by dragging and dropping the ready frames to our object, but in this case the collider will not follow the object.

Comment: "it does not follow the character's arm or knife." It does if you tell it to. I presume you tried to attach the collider to the game object representing the knife, or to its own object that you've animated to follow the knife's movement in the attack animation? Walk us through how you set up your character and animation, and we can help you find what you missed.

Comment: Let me explain with an example. The sword is not an external gameobject. https://imgur.com/EoloVtz  https://imgur.com/fufCPq6

Comment: So then you *make* an external game object, no? You are not limited to using a single object per character, even if the sprite is only displayed on one object.

Comment: But this won't solve my problem. Because the sword will move again and while it moves, it will go out of the collider just like in the picture and will not be able to damage the enemy object, right?  The main problem is that the collider pattern does not automatically wrap around objects that change shape during gameplay.

Comment: No, because you add an animation that moves the object with the sword's collider in sync with the sprite animation.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave the body, arm and sword to a single object in separate parts, then I prepared the animation from the unity's own animation window, so there was no problem with the colliders.  In the way I tried, there was a ready-made 10-frame attack animation, I gave it directly to the character, I set the transitions from the animator window, so it doesn't happen that way.  Now I'll have to draw all my sprites from scratch :)

Comment: want to post your solution as an Answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is make melee combat for your player.
You should look in physics2d section of overlapping circles and stuff.
But you can also look up brackeys tutorial for melee combat which explain everything perfectly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiVz1k-fEs

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained *how* to apply "overlapping circles and stuff" to solving the melee combat problem.